# Percentage from subtraction

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, statistics

I currently have an issue with a statistics sheet for a sports team. If I have a total amount of practices, with the number of days missed subtracted for each player. How do I turn that into a percentage of their attendance?

Comment: pls share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1):

```
=TEXT(D2/B2, "0.00%")
```

[image: 0]

which can also be:

```
=TEXT((B3-C3)/B3, "0.00%")
```

[image: 0]

or in one go:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(TEXT((B2:B-C2:C)/B2:B, "0.00%")))
```

[image: 0]